# Count Should show zero value if it null

Tags: mysql

I am using MYSQL DB

I have table joborder when I select with case getting no date I need to show zero like

```
select * from joborder;
10

select * from joborder where jobid='ID';
null
```

it should show 0 ?

Comment: you mean when you do a COUNT(*) ?

Comment: how can select * from joborder; return 10? is there only filed in the table?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `IFNULL` on your mysql query

LIKE `select IFNULL((select ID from joborder where jobid='ID'),0);`

Comment: i have multiple column to select main query like above query need to add id,name,job column then?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you need value where ever it exists and 0 where it is null.
Use your query as per below:

```
SELECT IFNULL(order_value,0) AS 'order_value' FROM joborder WHERE jobid='ID';
```

---

check below:

```
SELECT IFNULL(t21.n1,0) n1 ,t22.n2 FROM t1 AS t21 RIGHT JOIN (SELECT n2 FROM t2) t22 ON t22.n2=t21.n1;
```

Comment: Thanks but i am using subquery in main query getting zero only in t2 have 10 records but t1 no records. query is like select ifnull(n1,0),t22.n2 from t1 ,(select n2 from t2) t22;

Comment: as t1 does not have any record then you need to use right join instead of simple comma join...Further if you can provide me table wise some dummy data and your requirement then I can help you.

Comment: Table script is
create table t1 ( n1 integer,n3 integer,n4 integer);
 
create table t2 (n2 integer);
 
insert into t2 value(1);
insert into t2 value(1);
insert into t2 value(1);
 
select n1,t22.n2 from t1 ,(select n2 from t2) t22;
null

Comment: Even your requirement is not clear, also it is not clear that there is any relation between these 2 tables or not....you can check query I am posting in my answer. If it is not what you want then elaborate your actual requirement as why you are joining 2 tables even 1 is blank and for joining 2 tables logically there should be some relationship between them.